# Namespace prefixes in SOAP envelope cause parsing error: "Server was unable to read request"

Tags: java, .net, soap

I have a client who is attempting to use our .Net WebService with their Java environment. They're using 'javax.xml.soap.*' which requires a namespace prefix.  These same namespace prefixes cause parsing exceptions on our end.

> SoapServerMessage.Exception  :  "Server was unable to read request."

We are using 'System.Web.Services.WebService'

Here is a request they are trying to pass through:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ct:CredentialsSoapHeader xmlns:ct="http://ourwebsite.com/webservices/"
                            xsi:type="WebServiceKeyCredentials">
    <Key>demoKey</Key>
    <Password>demoPassword</Password>
  </ct:CredentialsSoapHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ct1:GetUserID xmlns:ct1="http://ourwebsite.com/webservices/">
      <EmailAddress>example@somewebsite.com</EmailAddress>
  </ct1:GetUserID>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The generated response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
ETag: ""
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2012 19:28:20 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

As soon as I strip away the namespace prefix, the request works fine.  I'm not very familiar with this system but I will try to provide any information as needed.

Thank you in advance for any help that can be provided!